# How to revert the auto-vacuum settings for a table in postgresql?

Tags: postgresql, performance, amazon-rds, autovacuum

I can update the autovacuum settings for a table using ALTER TABLE commands as follows:

```
ALTER TABLE <MY_TABLE_NAME> SET (autovacuum_vacuum_scale_factor = 0.02);
```

But am not able to figure out (was not able to find in the docs) how these settings can be reverted (if need be), thereby making the table to utilize the global autovacuum setttings?

The configurations are visible in the pg_class catalogue using

```
SELECT reloptions FROM pg_class WHERE relname='<MY_TABLE_NAME>'
```

Comment: Is it not just `ALTER TABLE ... RESET (<setting>)` ?

Comment: I tried this earlier but it was failing at that time (may be I had an incorrect syntax) - this works, thanks!!!

Comment: I think it needs the `( ... )` around the setting name which is not an obvious thing if you are only changing one setting.

Comment: Can you post your comment as an answer? I will mark it as accepted - it may help others who stumble upon this question later!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To reset a changed setting is just `ALTER TABLE ... RESET (<setting>)`. The bit that can be confusing is that the parentheses are required.